# How can i create a UPI QR code in android kotlin, and after scanning it the payment should be successful

Tags: android, kotlin, qr-code, upi

I've been trying to implement upi transaction from my app itself using UPI intent method, even after providing the merchant id i got from my google pay business account, it shows too risky payment, so i was thinking of creating a qr code for payment in android app itself and later the user can use it to scan and make the payment. Can someone give me code for how can i implement this ?
Thank you !

Hope it'll get solved, i want to get the payment directly in my bank account using that qr code